# Form/Button Issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working a web page for my wife and adding a PayPal checkout button, although not using their standard button.  For some reason, this code works when I put it into a WordPress block, but not when I view the page in a browser? Tried multiple browsers.

```css
.text-sizing {
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0rem;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .btn-wrapper {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0.1rem;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .btn {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: 0px solid #400779;
            color:#400779;
            background: white;
            font-size: 7px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .btn:hover,
        .btn:active {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: 0px solid #400779;
            color:white;
            background: #400779;
            font-size: 7px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<div class="btn-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXx">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Preorder Signed Copy">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What means 'does not work'? If it's a display issue, I assume that inside Wordpress there is additional global CSS present that impacts the form/button.

Comment: The formatting is not correct or even close to what I was expecting.  The buttons behave correctly, but the formatting is way off...is there a way to make sure I am only using the formatting I have documented above?  Should I be more specific in the naming?

Comment: The confusion is that it appears (formatting) correctly in the WordPress Preview, but not the Web Page...

Comment: It's tedious but you can inspect the messed-up button, notice all css properties that it should not have, and explicitly reset them to default values in your custom css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I was using the wrong CSS tags.  It should be 'input [type=XXX]'

```
<style>
input { text-align: center;
            padding: 0.1rem;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
}
.input-wrapper {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0.1rem;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }         
input[type=submit], input[type=submit]:active, input[type=submit]:focus {                         
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: 0px solid #400779;
            color:#400779;
            background: white;
            font-size: 7px;
            cursor: pointer;
  }          
  input[type=submit]:hover {   
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: 0px solid #400779;
            color:white;
            background: #400779;
            font-size: 7px;
            cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```